# Display the employees of the most popular manager?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

How can I display the employees of the most popular manager?
So, I've got this table and I need to have the first and last names of the employees of the most popular manager (Here it's going to be manager with id = 124).

The query should show first_name and last_name and manager_id.

How can I do that?

I guess it should count manager_id and order in desc, then limit 1, so to have only the top manager and somehow to show his employess

Comment: mysql <> sql-server <> oracle <> postgres: I removed these conflicting tags, please add only the relevant one.

Comment: How do you define the most popular manager or department?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @GMB maybe subquery to count manager_id, order in desc and limit 1

Comment: @DaleK oracle sql

Comment: @kikimonchik feel free to tag Oracle, just *don't* scatter tag every RDBMS as its annoying to people who are experts on other RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without any self-joins by using analytic functions. Count the employees with the same manager and then generate a ranking on the employee-count-per-manager from highest to lowest and then filter to show only the top ranked employees:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT e.*,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   (
    SELECT e.*,
           COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY manager_id ) AS num_emps_with_same_manager
    FROM   employees e
  ) e
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

So, for you test data (unnecessary columns removed):

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees ( employee_id, manager_id ) AS
SELECT 100, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 101 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 205, 101 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 206, 205 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 149, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 174, 149 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 176, 149 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 178, 149 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 141, 124 FROM DUAL;
```

The query outputs all the details of the employees with the manager who has the highest number of direct employees:

> ```
> EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_ID | NUM_EMPS_WITH_SAME_MANAGER | RNK
> ----------: | ---------: | -------------------------: | --:
>         149 |        100 |                          4 |   1
>         101 |        100 |                          4 |   1
>         102 |        100 |                          4 |   1
>         124 |        100 |                          4 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=562440defa92889a222fe06afefe99fb)*

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display the employees of the most popular manager?

If you are running Oracle 12.1 or higher, you can use window functions for sorting, along with a row-limiting clause:

```
select 
    e.*,
    m.first_name manager_first_name,
    m.last_name manager_last_name
from employees e
inner join employees m on m.employee_id = e.manager_id
order by count(*) over(partition by e.manager_id) desc
fetch next 1 rows with ties
```

The query self-joins the table to associate each employee with his manager; then we sort the resultset by descending count of employees of the same manager, and filter on the top record(s), allowing ties (this retains only employees that relate to the manager that has most employees).

---

In earlier versions, one option is to aggregate by manager and rank them by number of employees in a subquery, and use that for filtering:

```
select 
    e.*,
    m.first_name manager_first_name,
    m.last_name manager_last_name
from employees e
inner join employees m on m.employee_id = e.manager_id
inner join (
    select manager_id, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from employees
    group by manager_id, first_name, last_name
) x on x.rn = 1 and x.manager_id = e.manager_id
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, but this thing pops out  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @kikimonchik: which version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @kikimonchik: ok. The syntax I provide works in Oracle >= 12. I added another solution to my answer for earlier versions.

Comment: what should i have after AND?

Comment: @kikimonchik: that's a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing that @MT0 showed in his answer. Mine is more of a comment to alter it slightly but i am unable to comment (reputation points lacking) so adding as a new answer (sorry).

```
with q1 as (
select
 employee_id, manager_id,
 COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY manager_id ) AS num_emps_with_same_manager
from employees e
),
q2 as (
select 
  employee_id, manager_id, 
  num_emps_with_same_manager,
  RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC ) AS rnk,
  min(manager_id) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC, manager_id ASC)  over () as most_pop_mgr_asc_id
from q1
)
select * 
from q2
where 1=1
--and rnk = 1
and manager_id = most_pop_mgr_asc_id 
order by 1
;
```

gives most popular mgr also.

EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID NUM_EMPS_WITH_SAME_MANAGER        RNK MOST_POP_MGR_ASC_ID

---

```
    101        100                          4          1                 100
    102        100                          4          1                 100
    124        100                          4          1                 100
    149        100                          4          1                 100
```

Another way to do the same but making it more interesting/involved is to get the list of employees belonging to the most popular manager as well as another manager (chosen 3rd most popular manager).

```
with q1 as (
select 
   employee_id, manager_id, COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY manager_id ) AS num_emps_with_same_manager 
from employees e
),
q2 as (
select 
  employee_id, manager_id, num_emps_with_same_manager,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC ) AS rnk,
  min(manager_id) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC, manager_id ASC)  over () as most_pop_mgr_asc_id,
  min(num_emps_with_same_manager) keep (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC, manager_id ASC)  over () as most_pop_mgr_num_emps,
  listagg(employee_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER by employee_id ASC) OVER (PARTITION BY manager_id) as mgr_emps
from q1
),
q3 as (
select 
  q2.num_emps_with_same_manager as mgr_#emps, q2.manager_id as mgr, q2.rnk, q2.most_pop_mgr_asc_id as pop1_mgr, q2.most_pop_mgr_num_emps as pop1_mgr_#emps,
  cast(NTH_VALUE(min(mgr_emps), 1) OVER (ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as varchar2(20)) as pop1_mgr_emps,
  cast(min(case when rnk = 1 then mgr_emps end) over () as varchar2(20)) as pop1_mgr_emps_alt,
  cast(NTH_VALUE(min(manager_id), 3) OVER (ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as integer) as pop3_mgr,
  cast(NTH_VALUE(min(num_emps_with_same_manager), 3) OVER (ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as integer) as pop3_mgr_#emps,
  cast(NTH_VALUE(min(mgr_emps), 3) OVER (ORDER BY num_emps_with_same_manager DESC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as varchar2(20)) as pop3_mgr_emps,
  cast(min(case when rnk = 3 then mgr_emps end) over () as varchar2(20)) as pop3_mgr_emps_alt
from q2
where 1=1
--and rnk = 1
--and manager_id = most_pop_mgr_asc_id 
group by manager_id, num_emps_with_same_manager, rnk, most_pop_mgr_asc_id, most_pop_mgr_num_emps, case when rnk = 1 then mgr_emps end, case when rnk = 3 then mgr_emps end
order by 1 desc
)
select * 
from q3
where rnk = 1
;
```

gives

```
 MGR_#EMPS        MGR        RNK   POP1_MGR POP1_MGR_#EMPS POP1_MGR_EMPS        POP1_MGR_EMPS_ALT      POP3_MGR POP3_MGR_#EMPS POP3_MGR_EMPS        POP3_MGR_EMPS_ALT   
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------- -------------------- --------------------
         4        100          1        100              4 101,102,124,149      101,102,124,149             101              2 200,205              200,205
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY MANAGER_ID DESC
```